# SELECTing the column names for another SELECT - possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, reflection, monetdb

I have a table t1 with a 'foo' column, and records containing 'bar' and 'baz' in column 'foo'. I also have a table t2 with columns 'bar', 'baz' and 'quux'. I want to do something like the following:

```
SELECT (SELECT foo from t1) FROM t2;
```

that is, get the two column names from t1 and query those columns of t2. If I try to do this with MonetDB, I get an error message:

```
cardinality violation (2>1)
```

so,

- is there some other way to do this with MonetDB?
- is this possible in MySQL? other DBMSes?

Example queries (or non-query directives followed by a query) are welcome.

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL to do this (`prepare` and `execute` in MySQL).

Comment: No, this is generally not possible in RDBMSs, SQL specification includes subqueries used in the select list and those return data, not sg that would be part of the outer sql query. Most RDBMSs offer some feature allowing you to create sql commands dynamically, but by allowing the execution of an arbitrary string as an sql command.

Comment: @Shadow: Well, the thing is, MonetDB _does_ execute the inner query. I just need to somehow get to convert a vector into a sequence of strings. I realize that might not be possible but it's not because it's "generally" not possible.

Comment: It's possible (dynamic Sql) in many DBMSes, but every DBMS has its own   dynamic Sql tools.

Comment: @Serg: If you give an example for a specific DBMS I'll upvote it.

Comment: @einpoklum: I never said that the RDBMSs will not execute the subquery in the select list. They do. However, the returned values will never ever form part of the outer query's syntax, they are just viewed as values.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to select the columns into a variable and then use that variable to get tables

something like the following (it is not the actual implementation)

declare @colname varchar(250)

select @colname=foo  from t1

select @colname from t2

this may be help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can accomplish it in SQL Server

```
-- Create #T1 which contains names of columns and #T2 which contains the actual columns

CREATE TABLE #T1(colname nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO #T1 (colname) VALUES ('b')
INSERT INTO #T1 (colname) VALUES ('c')
CREATE TABLE #T2(a int IDENTITY(1,1), b DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(), c NVARCHAR(max) DEFAULT 'blah')
INSERT INTO #T2 DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #T2 DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #T2 DEFAULT VALUES
--@dSQL will contain the actual SQL string to be executed
DECLARE @dSQL nvarchar(max) = ' '
SELECT @dsql = CONCAT(@dsql,'[',colname,'],') FROM #T1
SELECT @dsql = CONCAT('SELECT',LEFT(@dsql,LEN(@dsql)-1),' FROM #T2')
--You can see the SQL query being executed
PRINT @dsql
--Actually execute it
exec sp_executesql @dsql
```

Comment: Provided dynamic Sql has no parameters EXEC (@dsql) suffice. You may wish to add parameters to your example to show `sp_executesql` advantages for the case.

Answer (score 0):

MS Sql dynamic sql example.

```
create table t1(foo varchar(100))
insert t1(foo)
values('bar,baz');

create table t2(bar int, baz int)
insert t2 (bar, baz)
values
  (1,100),
  (3,300);

declare @cmd varchar(max);
select @cmd= 'select '+ (select top(1) foo from t1) + ' from t2';

EXEC (@cmd);
```

Result

```
    bar baz
1   1   100
2   3   300
```

Or may be foo contains column names in different rows, not exactly clear from your question.

```
create table t1(foo varchar(100))
insert t1(foo)
values('bar'),('baz');

create table t2(bar int, baz int)
insert t2 (bar, baz)
values
  (1,100),
  (3,300);

declare @cmd varchar(max);
select @cmd= 'select '+ stuff((select ','+  foo from t1 for xml path('')),1,1,'') + ' from t2';


EXEC (@cmd);
```